# How to setup external identity provider for MSAL js react spa?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to authenticate using msal js for my react application (Azure AD B2C). Microsoft authentication works perfectly. But I need to add more external identity providers such as Google to my authentication.
I have followed the steps given in the official documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin&pivots=b2c-user-flow

When I Run user flow I am able to sign in google but the user is not authenticated.

[screen when user sign into google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woRk7.jpg)

This is the screen that is given.
And the other thing is only if use Run user flow in Azure AD B2C I am able to do this.
If I normally use the sign in button it only shows microsoft authentication.

What am I missing ?

Can someone please help on this if possible ?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using different policy names in your application compared to when you use "run now"?

Answer (score 0):

Issues may arise as a result of previous Microsoft configuration under **App registrations**.  Verify below three  configurations once whether those are mapped to google identify provider or not

**Client ID** and **Client secret** and **Authorized redirect URIs**

here I found one [blog](https://thecodeblogger.com/2020/05/17/google-identity-provider-with-azure-ad-b2c/) relates to **Google Identity Provider with Azure AD B2C** configuration and implementation.